# Call Javascript from code behind function in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How to Call Javascript function from code behind after button click event;

```
 string popupScript = "<script language='javascript'>" +
                         "alert('hai');" +
                       "</script>";

                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "script", popupScript, true);
```

I tried above script but not working

Answer (score 6):

You already added the `script` tags, so pass `false` as last argument:

```
string popupScript = 
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
    "alert('hai');" +
    "</script>";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "script", popupScript, false);
```

or leave it to the framework:

```
string popupScript = "alert('hai');";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "script", popupScript, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` is an overloaded function you can also leave it without the last 'addScriptTags' boolean when you want to put in the script tags yourself. It defaults to false.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `language` attribute. Change it to `type='text/javascript'`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all of the advice of the others, if the element firing this event is in an update panel you will need a full post-back trigger.